# How to create a user-defined table type with powerdesigner 15

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-types, powerdesigner

We're maintaining the whole database schemma on a PD 15 PDM including procedures, triggers, user-defined data types, functions and so on. The RDBMS we are using is SQL Server 2008 R2 which supports user defined Table Types eg. (CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableIDS] AS TABLE(ID int not null )) . This is very usefull for reusabillity. However i can't find the way to create such a type in the PDM. It must be somewhere in the Domains section but i can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With 15.3, it looks like you can create an Abstract Data Type of type Table.